# PeopleCode: when to use the Value property on a field?

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

Some code is written to get data from a field without using the `.Value` property:

```
PS_BI_HDR.INVOICE
```

And other code uses the `.Value` property:

```
PS_BI_HDR.INVOICE.Value
```

What is the difference?

Are there times when one should be used instead of the other?

Answer (score 2):

`PS_BI_HDR.INVOICE` may implicitly use the `.Value` property in some cases (e.g. assignment), but it is a field reference.

(`PS_BI_HDR.INVOICE` is actually a simplified version of `GetRecord(Record.PS_BI_HDR).GetField(Field.INVOICE)`)

If you intend to use the value stored in the field, you should explicitly use the `.Value` property, if anything to avoid mistakes.

Comment: PS_BI_HDR.INVOICE could show the value without .Value but if we use GetRecord().GetField() we must use .Value to get field value

Comment: @kh.tab as I pointed out "_PS_BI_HDR.INVOICE may implicitly use the .Value property_" and as any programmer should tell you, never count on implicit functionality.